# C# Interactive TextBox for user to type in a Date DD/MM/AAAA

Tags: c#, validation, date, textbox, user-input

I have this TextBox: `StartDate` with `__/__/____` as it's default text. My question here is if I'm thinking too much on this cause I already have close to 100 lines of code just for this...

`StartDate` calls `KeyUpEvent_DateFormat` or `Date_FieldSelection` when the user presses a key, or clicks the control. These funcions turn `StartDate` into `txt`

`Debug_TxtBox` is another TexBox I use for myself to check what the function is actually doing.

`Date_FieldSelection`:

```
private void Date_FieldSelection(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txt = sender as TextBox;
            if (txt.SelectionStart > 5) { txt.Select(6, 4); } // Selects Year
    else    if (txt.SelectionStart > 2) { txt.Select(3, 2); } // Selects Month
    else                                { txt.Select(0, 2); } // Selects Day
}
```

`KeyUpEvent_DateFormat`:

```
private void KeyUpEvent_DateFormat(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txt = sender as TextBox;

    #region Number Pressed - Have done nothing with it still
    if (Control.ModifierKeys.ToString() == "None" && ((e.KeyValue >= 48 && e.KeyValue <= 57) || (e.KeyValue >= 96 && e.KeyValue <= 105))) //Digit
    {

    }
    #endregion
    #region Right/Left arrow pressed
    else if (e.KeyValue == 39 || e.KeyValue == 37) //Right || Left
    {
        // Checks whhere the cursor was before the function was called
        int InitialSelection = -1;
        if (e.KeyValue == 39) { InitialSelection = txt.SelectionStart - 1; }
        if (e.KeyValue == 37) { InitialSelection = txt.SelectionStart + 1; }

        // Year was Selected:     Right -> Year;       Left -> Month
                if (InitialSelection > 5 && e.KeyValue == 39) { txt.Select(6, 0); }
        else    if (InitialSelection > 5 && e.KeyValue == 37) { txt.Select(4, 0); }

        // Month was Selected:    Right -> Year;       Left -> Day
        else if (InitialSelection > 3 && e.KeyValue == 39) { txt.Select(6, 0); }
        else    if (InitialSelection > 3 && e.KeyValue == 37) { txt.Select(1, 0); }

        // Day was Selected:      Right -> Month;      Left -> Day
        else    if (InitialSelection < 4 && e.KeyValue == 39) { txt.Select(4, 0); }
        else    if (InitialSelection < 4 && e.KeyValue == 37) { txt.Select(1, 0); }

        // Calls this to select the characters
        Date_FieldSelection(sender, null);
    }
    #endregion
    #region Character Pressed (Includes SHIFT)
    else if (
        (e.KeyValue >= 65 && e.KeyValue <= 90) || // Letter
        (Control.ModifierKeys.ToString() == "Shift" && ((e.KeyValue >= 48 && e.KeyValue <= 57) || (e.KeyValue >= 96 && e.KeyValue <= 105))) // SpecialChar
    )
    {
        if (txt.SelectionStart > 0) { txt.Select(txt.SelectionStart - 1, 1); }
        else { txt.Select(0, 1); }
        if (txt.SelectedText != "/")
        {
            // txt.SelectedText = "_";
            string BackTxt = ""; // Text before selection
            string FrontTxt = ""; // Text after selection

            // gets BackTxt and FrontTxt
            if (txt.SelectionStart < txt.Text.Length) { BackTxt = txt.Text.Remove(txt.SelectionStart); }
            else { BackTxt = txt.Text; }
            if (txt.SelectionStart > 0) { FrontTxt = txt.Text.Remove(0, txt.SelectionStart); }
            else { FrontTxt = txt.Text; }

            // This is a mess, I know...
            // Char1 and Char 2 are the last and first chars from BackTxt and FrontTxt
            // SelectedIndex is the current position of the cursor, before any change
            int SelectedIndex = txt.SelectionStart;
            char Char1 = new char();// BackTxt.ToCharArray()[BackTxt.Length - 1];
            char Char2 = new char();//FrontTxt.ToCharArray()[0];


            // Replaces written character with "_" in BackTxt
            if (BackTxt.Length > 0)
            {
                Char1 = BackTxt.ToCharArray()[BackTxt.Length - 1];
                if (!char.IsNumber(Char1) && Char1 != '_' && Char1 != '/') { Char1 = '_'; char[] CharArray = BackTxt.ToCharArray(); CharArray[CharArray.Length - 1] = Char1; BackTxt = new string(CharArray); }
                if (BackTxt.EndsWith("/")) { BackTxt += "_"; }
            }

            // Replaces written character with "_" in FrontTxt
            if (FrontTxt.Length > 0)
            {
                Char2 = FrontTxt.ToCharArray()[0];
                if (!char.IsNumber(Char2) && Char2 != '_' && Char2 != '/') { Char2 = '_'; char[] CharArray = FrontTxt.ToCharArray(); CharArray[0] = Char2; FrontTxt = new string(CharArray); }
                if (FrontTxt.StartsWith("/")) { FrontTxt = "_" + FrontTxt; }
            }

            // This is a bugfix for when you write the day
            if (BackTxt.Length == 0 && !FrontTxt.StartsWith("__")) { BackTxt = "_"; }

            //Joins everything
            txt.Text = BackTxt + FrontTxt;

            // Takes back cursor position and calls Date_FieldSelection
            txt.SelectionStart = SelectedIndex;
            Date_FieldSelection(sender, null);
        }
        else { Date_FieldSelection(sender, null); }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

What is left to do:

- When the user clicks the control while it is like `__/5/____` it should change to `__/05/____` before selecting.
- prevent this: `99/__/____`
- prevent this: `31/02/____`
- prevent this: `__/__/ffff` -> `__/__/ff__` when you hold "f" in year
- and so on...

Is there an easy way to do this, or should I just keep going? It looks like too much work for a simple thing.

This field has to:

- Select Day/Month/Year when it's clicked - **done**
- Prevent non Numeric characters to enter - in progress (user can write `__________` after erasing text)
- Validate Day, Month, and year separately:

  - Day has to be less than 32
  - Month has to be less than 13
  - Year has to be higher than 1970 and equal or less than current (2017, for the moment)
- Validate Day, Month, and Year Together:

  - Day can't be higher than what the written month can handle (31, feb)
  - Day will depend on the year if 29/02 is in question

Is there an easy way out of this?

Comment: [MaskedTextBox Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: If it's winforms, what @GSerg says

Comment: ... or yet even better [DateTimePicker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Filburt DateTimePicker is perfect! Can't edit it's BackGround, nor forecolor though

Comment: If you want more control about your design, you should consider switching form WinForms to WPF. There are already some questions around delaing with inheriting from DateTimePicker and overriding `.BackColor` and `.ForeColor` on WinForms.

Comment: Wouldn't I need to recreate the whole thing from scratch? I'm at 10k lines of code and over 300 different objects. Besides, I'm working on this piece of software in my free time - And have to have it ready in 3 months